# Почему не доходят файлы до сервера?

Tags: reactjs, formik

У меня есть форма.

Все работает правильно и почти идеально, но есть проблема.

Запрос идет на правильный маршрут, но до сервера постоянно не доходят файлы.

Выбранные файлы попадают в стейт из таргета - єто работает.
Но в formData, там где консоль.лог - там постоянно пусто...

Не понимаю, что не так?

Форма:

```
    <Formik
        initialValues={{ images: [] }}
        onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            values.images.forEach((file) => {
                formData.append("images", file);
            });
            try {
                console.log(formData);
                await uploadImage(hero.id, formData);
                //dispatch(getHeroes());
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            } finally {
                setSubmitting(false); // разблокировать отправку формы после загрузки файла
            }
        }}
    >
        {({ setFieldValue, isSubmitting }) => (
            <Form>
                <div>
                    <label>Images:</label>
                    <input
                        type="file"
                        id="images"
                        name="images"
                        multiple
                        onChange={(event) =>
                            setFieldValue("images", [...event.target.files])
                        }
                    />
                    <ErrorMessage name="images" className="error" component="div" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                    Submit
                </button>
            </Form>
        )}
    </Formik>
```

Comment: При логировании переменных с типом `FormData`, содержимое самого `FormData` показано не будет. Если нужно увидеть _что внутри `FormData`_, то можно воспользоваться чем-то вроде `console.log([ ...formData.entries() ])`

Comment: Попробуйте еще console.dir